# referer not working in Production mode Symfony 2.3

Tags: symfony

I have added this option in security.yml, under firewall settings :

```
    use_referer: true
```

Now, I have created a link which is used for email confirmation. When I am in development mode, if i click on the link and not logged in to the application, I got to the login page and then after login the I go to email confirmation link. But in production mode this is not working after login It is redirecting me too the default target path.

Here is security.yml :

```
    firewalls:
      dev:
       pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
       security: false

     main:
      pattern: ^/
      my-login:
       login_path: /
       check_path: /login_check
       default_target_path: /default_root
       provider:   my_provide
       use_referer: true
```

EDIT : some more information

I have created exception listener, which checks the response and redirects user to login page if he/she is not authenticated. Previously it was working only in production mode, i made it working in dev mode and now referer is not working in dev mode too.

Is there any way that I can by pass exception listener for this particular route.?

Comment: cleared the prod cache afterwards?

Comment: yes...Ofcourse.. I have tried many things. also seen but not getting anything [http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/form_login.html]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer myself.. :)

I just skipped that particular path from checking in exception listener.

```
    $path = $event->getRequest()->getPathInfo();
    if($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY') == false) {
      if($path == "my/path") {
        // simply redirect to login page without clearing session and cookies
      } else {
        // clear session and redirect to login page so that referer does not contain any data
      }
    }
```